# Find p-values from varpart table in vegan package

Tags: r, variance, partitioning, vegan

I have conducted a variance partitioning in R with the `vegan` package to test how weather variables partition in the variance of the green-up day.

```
library(readr)
library(vegan)

data = read_csv('C:/path/data.csv)
out = varpart(data$greenup, ~ data$CAPE, ~ data$Temp, ~ data$precip, ~ data$WS)
out

Partition table:
                            Df R.square Adj.R.square Testable
[aeghklno] = X1              1  0.00873      0.00514     TRUE
[befiklmo] = X2              1  0.00357     -0.00004     TRUE
[cfgjlmno] = X3              1  0.03279      0.02929     TRUE
[dhijkmno] = X4              1  0.00029     -0.00333     TRUE
[abefghiklmno] = X1+X2       2  0.01935      0.01221     TRUE
[acefghjklmno] = X1+X3       2  0.03534      0.02832     TRUE
[adeghijklmno] = X1+X4       2  0.00878      0.00157     TRUE
[bcefgijklmno] = X2+X3       2  0.03652      0.02951     TRUE
[bdefhijklmno] = X2+X4       2  0.00621     -0.00102     TRUE
[cdfghijklmno] = X3+X4       2  0.03341      0.02638     TRUE
[abcefghijklmno] = X1+X2+X3  3  0.04303      0.03255     TRUE
[abdefghijklmno] = X1+X2+X4  3  0.02096      0.01024     TRUE
[acdefghijklmno] = X1+X3+X4  3  0.03547      0.02491     TRUE
[bcdefghijklmno] = X2+X3+X4  3  0.04023      0.02972     TRUE
[abcdefghijklmno] = All      4  0.04579      0.03181     TRUE
```

I would like to find if the variance partitioning of each variable is significant. I understand this is not feasible for the shared and residual parts.

Can I just look up critical values for Pearson R with 275 degrees of freedom at a 0.05  significance level? Or should I compute the p-value for each variable? If the latter, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have *P*-values directly from the `varpart` table. However, the table has column `Testable` which is just that: it tells you that it is possible to construct an `rda` model that can be tested. See the function help page (`?varpart`) that explains how to do this. Read also the warning about trying to test all models simultaneously.